# How to show Yoast SEO title in the front end as a shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, yoast

I'm looking for a way to show Yoast Seo Title in the frontend as shortcode.

For example: for showing page title as shortcode I've added

```
<?php function page_title_sc( ){ return get_the_title(); } add_shortcode( ‘page_title’, ‘page_title_sc’ );
```

to the functions.php then added `[page_title]`to the frontend, and it's ok. But I want the SEO page title (yoast seo). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should grab the Yoast SEO title for a post.  Put this in your shortcode callback and return `$title`:

```
$title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);

// so


function page_title_sc() {
    global $post_id;

    $title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);

    // may want to fallback to default title if SEO title is not set
    if (!$title) {
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    }

    return $title;
}
add_shortcode( 'page_title', 'page_title_sc' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding.

It returns page title, not seo title. :(
I'm interested in showing seo title on every page (not only on posts).